# Using product ID parameter in GraphQL query in Shopify API (C#)

Tags: .net, graphql, shopify-api

I'm trying to get a list of products, including product categories from Shopify GraphQL API (their REST API responses don't contain the categories). I was able to make it work using the following query:

```
products(first: 250) 
{
    edges 
    { 
            node 
                { 
                id 
                title 
                handle 
                productCategory 
                            { 
                            productTaxonomyNode 
                                            { 
                                            fullName 
                                            }
                            }        
                }
    }
```

However I need to implement paging, in case there is a large number of products. I need to be able to ask for the first 250 products, then the next 250, and so on.
The query language provides an "after" keyword, which is described as:
"Returns the elements that come after the specified cursor."
I'm not sure what this cursor is, but given that products are returned sorted by product id, I'm working under the assumption that the cursor is a given product id.

So I've tried the following query:

```
 string query = "{ \"query\": \"query { products(first: 250, after: 7490375647481) { edges { node  ...
```

This gives me the following error:

> {"errors":[{"message":"Argument 'after' on Field 'products' has an
> invalid value (7490375647481).

I tried different ways of writing the product id: '7490375647481', '7490375647481', "7490375647481". All of this either returns a parsing error, or 400 Bad Request.

A query asking for a single product will also get me an invalid value error:

```
 {
  product(id: 7490375647481) {
    productCategory {
      productTaxonomyNode {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The value I'm using is a valid id, it's the id of one of the products returned from the API. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I solved it.

First of all, after switching to the latest version of the API, the "invalid value" error got a bit more specific: "string expected". This made me realize I'm not escaping the quotes properly. But how do you escape quotes in a string within a string that already has escaped quotes like this **\"** ? Answer is you escape the escape: **\\\"**

This changed the error I was getting to "malformed cursor", which made me google the cursor and find out it's not the id, but a field I need to request:

```
products(first: 250) 
{
    edges 
    { 
            cursor <- HERE!
            node 
                { 
                id 
                title 
                handle 
                productCategory 
                            { 
                            productTaxonomyNode 
                                            { 
                                            fullName 
                                            }
                            }        
                }
    }
```

The cursor looks like a long string of random characters. But it works.